# How to limit the amount of embedded entity's data in GET operations in api-platform

Tags: api-platform.com

Say we have two entities: `Question` and `Answer`. They are related as follows:

```php
#[ApiResource]
class Question
{
   //...
   
   #[ORM\OneToMany(mmappedBy: "question", targetEntity: Answer::class)]
   private Collection $answers;
}
```

```php
#[APiResource]
class Answer
{
   //...
   
   #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'answers')]
   #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
   private Question $question;
}
```

We are requested to return Question with only the 5 (five) more recent answers embedded in it, while we could use another endpoint to fetch all the question's answers paginated. How can we do that with API Platform? Thanks in advance for any help.